# Sort and search vectors by different criteria

Tags: c++, sorting, search, vector

**Class**

```
class Player{
    std::string name;       
    int score;      
    int id;         
};
```

I thought about how to write a code to sort and search vector of these classes by three criteria: name, id, and score.

The search what I want is to output the previous value and next value of the found element.

**The code that I thought of**

```
// v is a vector which the Player is randomly placed

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](Player& a, Player& b) {return a.getID() < b.getID(); });
std::vector<Player> ID_sorted_v = v;
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](Player& a, Player& b) {return a.getName() < b.getName(); });
std::vector<Player> Name_sorted_v = v;
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](Player& a, Player& b) {return a.getScore() < b.getScore(); });
std::vector<Player> Score_sorted_v = v;



std::cin >> input   // input is ID



for (vector<Player>::iterator search =
    find_if(ID_sorted_v.begin(), ID_sorted_v.end(),
        [input](Player& p) {
            return (p.getID() == input);
        });
    search != ID_sorted_v.end();
            search = find_if(++search, ID_sorted_v.end(), [input](Player& p) {
            return (p.getID() == input);
                }
            ))
{
    cout << *(search - 1) << endl << *search << endl << *(search + 1) << endl << endl;
}

for (vector<Player>::iterator search =
    find_if(Name_sorted_v .begin(), Name_sorted_v .end(),
        [input](Player& p) {
            return (p.getID() == input);
        });
    search != Name_sorted_v .end();
            search = find_if(++search, Name_sorted_v .end(), [input](Player& p) {
            return (p.getID() == input);
                }
            ))
{
    cout << *(search - 1) << endl << *search << endl << *(search + 1) << endl << endl;
}

for (vector<Player>::iterator search =
    find_if(Score_sorted_v.begin(), Score_sorted_v.end(),
        [input](Player& p) {
            return (p.getID() == input);
        });
    search != Score_sorted_v.end();
            search = find_if(++search, Score_sorted_v.end(), [input](Player& p) {
            return (p.getID() == input);
                }
            ))
{
    cout << *(search - 1) << endl << *search << endl << *(search + 1) << endl << endl;
}
```

**Desired Results**

```
// Player's <<Operator is overloaded
id 
name:dpygiewhuodfkfu, id:27        , score:206835634
name:jcawlfye       , id:30        , score:534327206
name:nwwffdkgvnegzio, id:31        , score:244395501

name
name:jcawcytbtbc    , id:1535712   , score:552239646
name:jcawlfye       , id:30        , score:534327206
name:jcawuqyvbttcrpq, id:559488    , score:495512171

score 
name:kawuzofo       , id:1030200   , score:534327131
name:jcawlfye       , id:30        , score:534327206
name:intny          , id:1770826   , score:534328056
```

I think the code is problematic in that it requires too much memory to prepare search.
How can I make this code easier and simpler? I thought about it for many hours, but I couldn't think of a better way.
Is that an impossible question?

Comment: You could go with a vector of pointers: `std::vector<Player const*> nameSorted(v.size(), nullptr); std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), nameSorted.being(), [](Player const& p) { return &p; });` This way the vector uses 8 byte per element (+ `O(1)` total) assuming an 64 bit architecture .

Comment: I'm not familiar with pointer vectors, so I'm asking you a question. How can a pointer vector be compatible with find_if by type casting?

Comment: The predicate of `find_if` receives a reference to an element. Since copying pointers is cheap enough, a predicate `[](Player const& p) { ... }` used with the copied vector can be transformed into `[](Player const* p) { ... }`. Of course you need to dereference the pointer or use the arrow operator. Note that the pointers must not be dereferenced after the elements in the original vector change address which can happen, if you add new elements to `v`...

Comment: @MeoH I'm still confused a little about what you're trying to achieve.  If the issue is finding the previous and next value for the item you searched for, why not simply `std::find_if` and use `std::prev` and `std::next` on the returned iterator (if found)?

Comment: Because I want to process the output of the previous value based on id and the output based on score and the output based on name at once.

Comment: Well, one thing you could do is you don't need 3 sorted vectors of players.  The first sort on ID is what you would do, but the other two sorts can be sorting a simple array of indices, not entire `vector`'s of Players and having them stored (thus less memory wasted_.  You then use the indices as offsets into the sorted ID vector.  Then it's a matter of writing a simple loop.  Basically there are several ways you could shorten the code, and lessen the memory used.

Comment: Also, I think a better place for your question would be [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since it is a question about improving working code.

Comment: As to using indices [look at this example, using your class](https://godbolt.org/z/GxYj9ovMs).  Note how we only actually sort the Player vector once.  The other two sorts sort an array of index values, corresponding to the Player vector.  Less wasted space, especially of the Player class gets larger.

Comment: I didn't know the Code Review site. Thank you for your good answer.

Comment: @MeoH -- To round things out, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8vfGqc8sP) is your code using the methods I mentioned.